# Connection to AWS Postgres SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, express, sequelize.js

I am new to AWS and NodeJS/Express server. The server should connect to AWS RDS Postgress Database.
I am developing using Visual Studio Code on MacOS

I get this error when I try to run my server:

```
Using ts-node version 8.4.1, typescript version 3.6.3
(node:2377) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user “userNB”
    at connection.connect.err (…node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:154:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (…..node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:191:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
```

I am saving my username, pass,...etc as environment variables in /.bash_profile

my Sequelize code:

```
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { config } from './config/config';
onst c = config.dev;


export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  "username": c.username,
  "password": c.password,
  "database": c.database,
  "host":     c.host,

  dialect: 'postgres',
  storage: ':memory:',
});
```

Is this kind of error related to my NodeJS code or AWS settings?
How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sequelize like this and it's working for me:

```
DATABASE_URI=postgresql://username:password@amazonhost:5432/database_name

export const sequelize = new Sequelize(DATABASE_URI);
```

Also make sure you've the correct password and the IP from which you're trying to connect is whitelisted for database. You can test this using postgres client cli.

Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried your method and got the same error. Then I checked my credentials, I realized that I've been using the username that I've created as a IAM user, instead of using the master's username that I created when I created the Databse. 

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Sure, you can accept the answer if it helped :) @N.albar

Answer (score 0):

you are missing sequelize params to create a new instance. create a new `sequelize` instance like this:

`const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: your_database_host,
  dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */
});`

for more information, see sequelize docss

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html